# i need some help on the rietz representation theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let T be a linear form and $\varphi$ a differential form. I want to show that there existes a Radon measure $ \mu_{T}$ and a unitary vector $\overrightarrow{T}$ such that: $$ T(\varphi)= \int < \varphi, \overrightarrow{T} > d \mu_{T}. $$
I verified the conditions of Riez reprentation theorem on T, and by the theorem i can only get: $$ T(\varphi)= \int  \varphi d \mu_{T}. $$
Please how can i get to include the vector $\overrightarrow{T}$ and get the resultat? Help